# jenkins job failing on build step Is a directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job which is failing on build step.

```
    stage('build') {
        steps {
            sh '${WORKSPACE}'
        }
    }
```

logs from jenkins server is as follows

```
    [Pipeline] sh
    + /root/.jenkins/workspace/dvmt-image-capture-manager-new
    /root/.jenkins/workspace/dvmt-image-capture-manager-new@tmp/durable-bb5f7b6c/script.sh: line 1: /root/.jenkins/workspace/dvmt-image-capture-manager-new: Is a directory
```

can someone please take a look and guide be what I could be doing wrong. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Edited your post and now the issue should be fairly obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sh “WORKSPACE” part because you are trying to execute on workspace and you are not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

sh '${WORKSPACE}' > sh "echo ${WORKSPACE}" if you after printing the workspace path else remove it